# Trying to update UIView from UITableView selected cell in sliding menu

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitableview, storyboard

Been working on this one for a while and am stuck. I have a sliding menu in my app that is a UITableView and what I'd like to happen is that when a cell is selected the topView will be updated to a UINavigationController that loads my UICollectionView. I am using storyboards and  currently I have a cross fading modal segue to load the new view for functionality purposes. Here is a screenshot and any help would be greatly appreciated. I know the view should be updated in the function

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

The top UIView is called topLayer

Screenshot available here: http://d.pr/i/idRo

Answer (score 0):

connect a manual triggered segue from topview to UINavigationController and give it an identifier. use that identifier as below:

```
     - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"topviewToNagivgationController"  sender:self];
        }
//else
    }
```

Comment: TopView isn't a viewcontroller though, so I'm having some trouble figuring out how I can connect a segue from that to the UINavigationController.

Comment: @user1911904, I think you cannot navigate from uiview to uiviewcontroller. So, please change top view as a uiviewcontroller. I am using same structure as above for facebook type  slide menu